# WinHttpRequest / Microsoft.XMLDOM vs. Cypress.Request POST

Tags: javascript, xml, post, vbscript, cypress

I apologize in advance for this poorly worded question.

I'm re-writing an older E2E test that performs a POST of an XML document to an internal site using vbScript. With WinHttpRequest and Microsoft.XMLDOM the data is accepted and appears as expected in the website. However, when I perform the "same" operation using Cypress I obtain different results.

My question: Is there difference in the way these two technologies perform the POST operation or am I missing something in the Cypress code?

Thanks in advance for any advice!

**VBS**

```
Dim xmlhttp, oXML
Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
xmlhttp.open "POST", "https://InternalWebSite.com/Orders/CXMLOrder.aspx", False
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-length", "1000"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Connection", "close"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "soapAction", ""
Set oXML = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
oXML.async = False
oXML.load(localPath & "\MyOrderFile.xml")
xmlhttp.send(oXML)
```

**CYPRESS**

```
it('Post Order File to Site', () => {
    const myOrderFile = 'C:\\Automation\\MyOrderFile.xml'
    cy
        .readFile(myOrderFile)
        .then(function (text) {
            cy.log(text)
            postXML(text)
         })
    })

function postXML(text) {
    return cy.request({ 
        url: 'https://InternalWebSite.com/Orders/CXMLOrder.aspx',
        method: 'POST',
        body: text,
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
            'content-length': '1000',
            'connection': 'close',
            'soapAction': ''
        }
    }
)}
```

Comment: You’ve got a `postXML()` but the function you’ve included is `fetchXML()`? Can you include `postXML()` as well, where is `fetchXML()` used?

Comment: Good catch!  Typo occurred when I was trying to format the code post.  I have edited the post.

Comment: Technically for the VBScript and the Cypress code to be doing the same thing the VBScript should send `xmlHttp.Send(oXML.xml)` instead of passing the `oXML` object reference as the [`xml` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms755989(v=vs.85)) contains the XML document body.

Answer (score 0):

The solution ended up being quite simple.

In the original VBS code the "**content-length**" was set to 1000 - my assumption was that if it worked for VBS it would also work for Cypress.  As it turns out setting  "**content-length**" based on the actual XML payload length was the trick.

**From:**
'content-length': '1000',

**To:**
'content-length': text.length,